# Exclude results from query with specific text in CLOB field

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I am looking to exclude records with the words 'rich text' in the NRS.FULL_TEXT (CLOB data type) field. I am working in oracle sql.

I tried using the NOT LIKE function and I received no results. Also, I tried the following code but received an error:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

```
    SELECT 
        PT.PATIENT_MRN AS MRN
        ,ORD.PATIENT_ID
        ,ORD.ORDER_DATE
        ,ORD.ORDER_TYPE
        ,ORD.ORDER_PROC
        ,ORD.SPECIMEN_SOURCE
        ,ORS.COMPONENT_NAME
        ,ORS.RESULT_TEXT
        ,NRS.FULL_TEXT
    FROM RDM.PATIENT                PT
    LEFT JOIN RDM.ORDERS            ORD ON PT.PATIENT_ID = ORD.PATIENT_ID 
    LEFT JOIN RDM.ORDER_RESULT      ORS ON ORS.ORDER_ID = ORD.ORDER_ID
    LEFT JOIN RDM.NOTE_RSLT         NRS ON ORD.ORDER_ID = NRS.ORDER_ID
    WHERE ORD.ORDER_DATE BETWEEN '01-JUL-2021 12:00:00 AM' AND '30-JUN-2022 11:59:59 PM'
    AND (FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, PT.BIRTH_DATE)/12)>18)   
    AND PT.PATIENT_MRN NOT IN (
    SELECT NRS.FULL_TEXT FROM RDM.NOTE_RSLT WHERE NRS.FULL_TEXT LIKE '%rich text%')
```

Comment: Could you please setup a fiddle which shows the issue and share the link? Using NOT LIKE works, see https://dbfiddle.uk/9wSMgYwS

Comment: You could also use INSTR(LOWER(full_text),'rich text') = 0, but as said, your issue is obviously not that LIKE or NOT LIKE would not work. There seems to be another problem. Sharing a fiddle link for us would allow to replicate this.

Comment: I am unsure what a fiddle is. I am relatively new at this.

Comment: Please open the link in my first comment. There you can add your create table commands, inserts etc. to build up your data. Then you can share the new link and we can replicate your issue and try out possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

We can use normal SQL functions with CLOB data when the CLOB is <= 4000, i.e. small enough to treat as VARCHAR2. But when we work with larger CLOBs it is best to use functions from the built-in Oracle DBMS_LOB package.

```
    SELECT 
        PT.PATIENT_MRN AS MRN
        ,ORD.PATIENT_ID
        ,ORD.ORDER_DATE
        ,ORD.ORDER_TYPE
        ,ORD.ORDER_PROC
        ,ORD.SPECIMEN_SOURCE
        ,ORS.COMPONENT_NAME
        ,ORS.RESULT_TEXT
        ,NRS.FULL_TEXT
    FROM RDM.PATIENT                PT
    LEFT JOIN RDM.ORDERS            ORD ON PT.PATIENT_ID = ORD.PATIENT_ID 
    LEFT JOIN RDM.ORDER_RESULT      ORS ON ORS.ORDER_ID = ORD.ORDER_ID
    LEFT JOIN RDM.NOTE_RSLT         NRS ON ORD.ORDER_ID = NRS.ORDER_ID
    WHERE ORD.ORDER_DATE BETWEEN '01-JUL-2021 12:00:00 AM' AND '30-JUN-2022 11:59:59 PM'
    AND (FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, PT.BIRTH_DATE)/12)>18)   
    AND PT.PATIENT_MRN NOT IN (
        SELECT NRS.FULL_TEXT 
        FROM RDM.NOTE_RSLT 
        WHERE dbms_lob.instr(NRS.FULL_TEXT, '%rich text%') > 0
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I still received the error message:  ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your responses. I was able to resolve this issue by using the
dbms_lob.substr function as follows:

```
SELECT 
    PT.PATIENT_MRN AS MRN
    ,ORD.PATIENT_ID AS PAT_ID
    ,ORD.ORDER_DATE AS ORD_DATE
    ,ORD.ORDER_TYPE AS ORD_TYPE
    ,ORD.ORDER_PROC AS ORD_PROC
    ,ORD.SPECIMEN_SOURCE AS SPECIMEN_SRC
    ,ORS.COMPONENT_NAME AS NOTE_TYPE
    ,ORS.RESULT_TEXT AS FINAL_DX
    ,DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(NRS.FULL_TEXT, 4000, 1) AS NOTES 
FROM RDM.PATIENT                PT
LEFT JOIN RDM.ORDERS            ORD ON PT.PATIENT_ID = ORD.PATIENT_ID 
LEFT JOIN RDM.ORDER_RESULT      ORS ON ORS.ORDER_ID = ORD.ORDER_ID
LEFT JOIN RDM.NOTE_RSLT         NRS ON ORD.ORDER_ID = NRS.ORDER_ID
WHERE ORD.ORDER_DATE BETWEEN '01-JUL-2021 12:00:00 AM' AND '30-JUN-2022 11:59:59 
 PM'
AND (FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, PT.BIRTH_DATE)/12)>18)
```

Afterwards, I was able to search for a string using WHERE...NOT IN. The CLOB field was greater that 4000 characters so this worked well for me.